# How do I solve this logical operator problem?

Tags: c++, math, logic, logical-operators

My professor gave us a logical operator worksheet from my C++ clas and I got stumped on this problem. 
If x = -2, y = 5, z = 0, and t = -4, what is the value of each of the following logical expressions?

```
3 * y / 4 < 8 && y >= 4
```

I get stuck on this step after I plug everything in.
3 < 8 && 5

I know that on the left 3 * 5= 15, and 15 / 4 = 3. Now the other side is where I get stuck at. I know 5 is true since it's greater than or equal to 4. But I don't know what to do with next when its 8 && 5. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you get `5` on the right side? `5 >= 4` is either true or false, so is `3 < 8`, not 8 and 5.

Comment: It might help to look up operator precedence and add parentheses accordingly.

Comment: Note that the `<` and `>=` will result in a boolean (true or false), not a number.

Comment: @scohe001 If that occurs what happens when I have 8 && True on the right side?

Comment: Well `&&` treats each of its operands as booleans, so `8` would be seen as `true` and you'd have `true && true`. But that's not what you're left with. `(3 < 8) && (5 >= 4)` shouldn't get you to `8 && true`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put parenthesis around the various sub-expressions in your expression by following [the order of precedence of operators and their associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

```
3 * y / 4 < 8 && y >= 4
```

is

```
(3 * y) / 4 < 8 && y >= 4
```

is

```
((3 * y) / 4) < 8 && y >= 4
```

is

```
(((3 * y) / 4) < 8) && y >= 4
```

is

```
(((3 * y) / 4) < 8) && (y >= 4)
```

That should give you a clear guideline of what the expression should evaluate to.

Comment: I got the answer, thank you! The parenthesis really helped!

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer, if you have enough reputation to do so. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Comment: @Angel, I'm glad I was able to help with use of the parenthesis. I hope you can use the strategy in the future to bring clarity to poorly written code.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an exercise in operator precedence. When precedence is taken into account, the statement `3 * y / 4 < 8 && y >= 4` is equivalent with

```
(((3 * y) / 4) < 8) && (y >= 4)
```

Substituting the variables, we have

```
(((3 * 5) / 4) < 8 && (5 >= 4)
```

After doing the math, we end up with

```
(3 < 8) && (5 >= 4)
```

3 is indeed lesser than 8, and 5 is indeed greater or equal than 4, so both sides of boolean `and` are true, and the whole expression is evaluated to true.